# for constexpr in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++20

I am writing a constexpr function and need to use a constexpr for. The loop can be manually expanded out by hand but I find that ugly in code and redundant.

How can I make a "constexpr for"?

Should I make a helper class? If so, how would I go about writing something like this:

```
#define for_constexpr( TYPE, VAR, START, CONDITION, END_OP, BODY ) \
    for_constexpr_helper< \
        TYPE, START, // TYPE START = 0; \
        [ ]( TYPE VAR ) constexpr { return CONDITION; }, \
        [ ] constexpr { END_OP; }, \
        [ & ]( TYPE VAR ) constexpr { BODY; } >( )
```

Where the usage is something like

```
int x = 0;
for_constexpr( int, i, 0, i < 3, ++i, x += i * 2 );
```

More specifically, how can I use `i` in a constexpr context, such as a template parameter?

What are my options?

Example code:

```
auto ret = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
    static_assert( i != 4 ); // just an example
    ret += i;
}
return ret;
```

This fails to be constexpr. Ugly example:

```
auto ret = 0;
ret += 1;
ret += 2;
ret += 3;
return ret; // works
```

Comment: I don't follow; can you show an example of the ugly-by-hand version?

Comment: `constexpr` functions can already use for loops.  What do you need out of it that it isn't giving you?

Comment: @NathanOliver using `i` as a template parameter;

Comment: @cigien added some example code

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/C4mtzB

Comment: I think you could use [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1306r1.pdf) which I think is in c++20, but no compiler implements it yet.

Comment: @cigien It is not in C++20.

Comment: Oh, pity, seems useful.

Comment: @cigien: It *will* be not only useful but usable once the iterator issues get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use macros to do this. If you are fine with "passing" the loop variable via

```
template <std::size_t i>
struct foo{
    constexpr void operator()() {
        static_assert(i != 3);
    }
};
```

Ie. put the body of your static loop inside the `operator()` then you can use the following:

```
template<template <std::size_t> class F, std::size_t... I>
auto static_for_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    (F<I>()(),...);
}


template<std::size_t N,template <std::size_t> class F,typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
constexpr void static_for(){
    static_for_impl<F>(Indices{});
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {    
    static_for<5,foo>();    
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Cdu7Kk)

Alternatively you can use `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>` as argument, so that it works with lambdas and does not require to write a class template (credit goes to @Artyer):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template<typename F, std::size_t... I>
auto static_for_impl(F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    (static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})), ...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename F>
constexpr void static_for(F&& f) {
    static_for_impl<F>(std::forward<F>(f), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    static_for<5>([](auto i) {
        static_assert(i != 5);
    });
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/h7QWPv)

While in C++20 you can use a template lambda (credit goes to @Jarod42):

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N, typename F>
constexpr void static_for(F&& f) {
    [&f]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        (static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{})), ...);
     }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    static_for<5>([](auto i) {
        static_assert(i != 5);
    });
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/wPbJzp)

Comment: Or alternatively calling with `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>` arguments, so you can use lambdas instead of template classes: https://godbolt.org/z/Ezw8tQ

Comment: @Artyer ah nice. Thats what I wanted but I didnt know how to get there. I will add it to the answer, but only tomorrow

Comment: @Artyer: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wPbJzp) with C++20 template lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 hope you don't mind that I added your code to the answer

Comment: @Artyer I added your code to the answer. It is much nicer that my original, but still I left it in just to show different ways. I can imagine cases where the need for a class template isnt really a restriction